# How to confirm minikube is using hyperkit

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When trying to run `minikube` with hyperkit, I was getting errors about xhyve not being installed. I installed that and reran `minikube start --vm-driver hyperkit` with no issues.

I was under the impression that hyperkit was a replacement for xhyve, not a supplement to it.

When I run `ps` I see both `com.docker.hyperkit` and `docker-machine-driver-xhyve` running.

How can I confirm that minikube is correctly using hyperkit?

Answer (score 12):

[Docker for Mac](https://www.docker.com/docker-mac) changed virtualization layer few times last years, and it can confuse users after updates of environment.

If the process list shows both [com.docker.hyperkit](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver) and [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve) processes is probably due
to docker-machine environment which was previously set up using [docker-machine-driver-xhyve](https://github.com/machine-drivers/docker-machine-driver-xhyve).

You may consider cleaning up installation by

- stopping Docker (from command line or from tray icon),
- next removing machines created by `docker-machine` tool.

I can also suggest to remove current minikube installation using

```
minikube stop && minikube delete
```

and start fresh one with:

```
minikube start --v=10 --vm-driver=hyperkit"
```

That will add additional verbose output of building minikube environment.

Comment: That looks more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 6):

This will give you the current driver for the current machine. Replace the second "minikube" with the name of your profile if you're using the `--profile` flag.

`$ cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json  | grep DriverName`

Answer (score 1):

Strange, considering **[Hyperkit](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver)** is supposed to replace xhyve eventually.

Make sure Hyperkit is built/installed and referenced by tour PATH.
And that you are using the latest [docker-ce for Mac](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac).

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to get a list of each hypervisor instance that's running with hyperkit:

```
$ ps -ef | grep hyperkit
```

If minikube is running in hyperkit then the name 'minikube' should show up in the output:

```
0 29305     1   0 Tue06PM ??       515:01.32 /usr/local/bin/hyperkit -A -u -F /Users/me/.minikube/machines/minikube/hyperkit.pid -c 2 -m 2000M -s 0:0,...
```

The instance labeled as 'com.docker.hyperkit' is the process that's being used by Docker and is NOT the minikube instance.